# Create list item by restful

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, rest

**Code:**

```
  function createListItem() { 
            var item =  {
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.listnameListItem" },   
                "Title": "testsetsetset",
                "Column1": "Test", 
                "Column2": "Test" , 
            } ;

        $.ajax({
              url: apphostweb + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items",
            type: "POST",       
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  
           data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successful");            
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Failure");
            }
        });

}
```

I can insert the title to the list, but after I added the column1 and column2 field in the request. There is a error:

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A
>   type named 'SP.Data.listnameListItem' could not be resolved by the
>   model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a
>   valid type."}}}

Can we create whole item using this method? OR another method should be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is related to `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` must be specified in `__metadata`. Your error message seems `SP.Data.listnameListItem` is not the valid value for `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. This value can be found in the following end-point.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('listName')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

Make a GET request to the above URL or hit directly to the browser and find the value of `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. Finally add this value in `_metadata`.